# Bezier Interpolation messes up Animation Loop

Tags: animation, graph-editor

My Animation loops are never smooth when they loop. This is a bone from an animation (I've made a habit of saving the default position into keyframe 0 which is not used by the animation)

The green bar is the part that loops:

[image]

This image shows what happens when the animation starts Looping. The Green Bars mark the same bit as the top picture. The cyan circle shows the problem. What I used to do is double the animation and simply use what is within the Blue bar. I would go on and fix the keyframes in the middle manually.

[image]

Since I am doing A LOT of animations lately with A LOT of bones, I cannot go through this process everytime. How can I smooth the animation without complicating things too much?

And please don't tell me that dragging those THINGS is the only way.

[image]

Comment: and that graph cycles alright I assume?.  In image in link above you have 5 keyframes in your cycle.  If you copy  frame 4 and paste it as a keyframe to left of keyframe 1 the same amount it is left of  frame 5, and similarly with the other end. Your cycle will be keyframes 2 to 6, keyframe 1 and keyframe 7 are making sure "alpha" is the same.  Actually end your cycle one frame to left of keyframe 6.  Can be automated easily with a script.

Comment: .. or if you are open to using the  [NLA Editor can influence the blend in blend out.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/nla/properties_modifiers.html#active-track)

Comment: Thanks, there was a misunderstanding between "frame" and "keyframe" :-)